# For loop to separate a string with spaces (Java)

Tags: java, string, spaces

Is there a way to create some type of For loop to separate a string with spaces?
So far I can display a string and find how many characters it has.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.String;

public class Word{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

     int b;

    String word;

    System.out.println ("Enter a word: ");
    word = scan.next();

    b = word.length();

    System.out.println (word);
    System.out.println (b);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this?  i.e. do you need to understand the principle, or do you need to get the job done?

Comment: Do you have a string with spaces that you want to split, or do you want to space out a string by inserting spaces?

Comment: Space out a string by inserting spaces, sorry.

Comment: Where do you want to insert spaces?

Answer (score 8):

As an alternative to `Scanner`, you can do something like the following:

```
String[] parts = line.split(" ");
for (String part : parts) {
    //do something interesting here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method in the String class, like this:

```
String line = "a series of words";
String[] words = line.split("\\s+");
```

It will return a `String[]` with the individual words in `line`, for the above example it will produce this:

```
{"a", "series", "of", "words"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.split` to split the sentence into an array of words.. something like

```
string[] words = word.split(" ");
for (String s: words)
{
    System.out.println(s);
    System.out.println("\n");
}
```

Comment: Note this is not Java loop syntax. Try `for (String s: words)`

Comment: @LarsH - thanks for that. was using C#, corrected now

Comment: Thanks for correcting the code. However I just now read the OP's comments, saying that he or she wanted to *insert* spaces into the string. ::shrug::

Answer (score 0):

have you tried looking at the java API?
there are a lot of different functions you can use ...
top of my head split would work nicely and you wouldn't even have to write a loop

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/

Comment: It has to be a for loop, sorry

Comment: can you clarify the question.. is the objective to print out each word separated by a space ?

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, but I feel like this is a learning exercise so this should put you on the right path. In the for loop you access each character of the word as a sub-string and concatenate a space on the end (end of the word as well).

```
string word2 ="";
for (int i = 0; i<word.length-1;i++) {
    word2 = word.substring(i, i+1)+" ";
}
```

Comment: Sorry, missed that, take a look at your previous code. You've done the same thing before. (consider substituting b)

Answer (score 0):

I am using following code:

```
Arrays.stream(yourString.split(" ")).forEach( element -> {
                // do something with each element
                System.out.println(element + "\n");
            });
```